# ARM template for Appservice integrating with existing VNET Subnets

Tags: azure, templates, arm, azure-rm-template

i have an ARM template that creates a new App Service in an existing AppPlan and a new KeyVault that allows access to the App Service's Identity. I would also like to add an existing VNET/Subnet to the App Service but I am not having any luck. My script runs but the VNET/Subnet does not get tied to the App Service. Thanks for any help.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "subscriptionId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "keyVaultUserObjectId": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "ObjectID for user to get full rights to keyvault. Default is Henry's I account"
      }
    },
    "hostingEnvironment": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Division": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "OwnerName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "aValue",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Used to distinquish who in is responsible for the resource"
      }
    },
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "hostingPlanName",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Appservice Plan. Default = . Must supply one for Prod"
      }
    },
    "environmentName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "uat",
      "allowedValues": [ "uat", "qa", "prod" ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "What environment will this run in"
      }
    },
    //try to collapse this based on environment name
    "environmentType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "nonProd",
      "allowedValues": [ "nonProd", "prod" ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "What type environment will this run in"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "suffix": "[uniqueString(resourceGroup().id,resourceGroup().location)]",
    "environmentBasedValues": {
      "nonProd": {
        "fullDeployedName": "[tolower(substring(concat(parameters('name'),'-',substring(parameters('environmentName'),0,1),'-',variables('suffix')),0,24))]",
        "keyVaultDeployedName": "[tolower(substring(concat(parameters('name'),'-',substring(parameters('environmentName'),0,1),'-',variables('suffix')),0,24))]",
        "hostingPlanDeployedName": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]", 
        "serverFarmResourceGroupDeployedName": "[resourceGroup().name]" 
      },
      "prod": {
        "fullDeployedName": "[tolower(substring(concat(parameters('name'),'-',variables('suffix')),0,24))]",
        "keyVaultDeployedName": "[tolower(substring(concat(parameters('name'),'-',variables('suffix')),0,24))]",
        "hostingPlanDeployedName": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]", 
        "serverFarmResourceGroupDeployedName": "[resourceGroup().name]"
      }
    },
    "Agency": "AGENCY",
    "OwnerName": "[parameters('OwnerName')]",
    "alwaysOn": true,
    "currentStack": "dotnetcore",
    "phpVersion": "OFF",
    "errorLink": "[concat('https://',variables('environmentBasedValues')[parameters('environmentType')].fullDeployedName,'.scm.azurewebsites.net/detectors?type=tools&name=eventviewer')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('environmentBasedValues')[parameters('environmentType')].fullDeployedName]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      //"location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "Agency": "[variables('agency')]",
        "OwnerName": "[variables('OwnerName')]",
        "Application": "[parameters('name')]",
        "Division": "[parameters('Division')]",
        "Environment": "[parameters('environmentName')]"
      },
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "dependsOn": [],

      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('environmentBasedValues')[parameters('environmentType')].fullDeployedName]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "ANCM_ADDITIONAL_ERROR_PAGE_LINK",
              "value": "[variables('errorLink')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT",
              "value": "[parameters('environmentName')]"
            }
          ],
          "metadata": [
            {
              "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
              "value": "[variables('currentStack')]"
            }
          ],
          "phpVersion": "[variables('phpVersion')]",
          "alwaysOn": "[variables('alwaysOn')]"
        },
        "serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', variables('environmentBasedValues')[parameters('environmentType')].serverFarmResourceGroupDeployedName, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('environmentBasedValues')[parameters('environmentType')].hostingPlanDeployedName)]",
        "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('hostingEnvironment')]",
        "clientAffinityEnabled": true
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "name": "virtualNetwork",
          "properties": {
            "subnetResourceId": "[resourceId('NetworkRG','Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/Subnets/','VNETNAME' ,'SUBNETNAME')]",
            "swiftSupported": true
          },
          "type": "config",
          "dependsOn": [

            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('environmentBasedValues')[parameters('environmentType')].fullDeployedName)]"
           // "[concat(resourceId('NetworkRG','Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks','PrimaryVNet'))]"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "name": "[variables('environmentBasedValues')[parameters('environmentType')].keyVaultDeployedName]",
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
      "tags": {
        "Agency": "[variables('agency')]",
        "OwnerName": "[variables('OwnerName')]",
        "Application": "[parameters('name')]",
        "Division": "[parameters('Division')]",
        "Environment": "[parameters('environmentName')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "sku": {
          "family": "A",
          "name": "Standard"
        },
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
        "accessPolicies": [
          {
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('environmentBasedValues')[parameters('environmentType')].fullDeployedName),'2018-11-01','Full').identity.principalId]",
            "permissions": {
              "keys": [],
              "secrets": [ "get","list" ],
              "certificates": []
            }
          },
          {
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[parameters('keyVaultUserObjectId')]", 
            "permissions": {
              "keys": [ "all" ],
              "secrets": [ "all" ],
              "certificates": [ "all" ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "resourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceGroup().name]"
    },
    "mykeyVaultUserObjectId": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('keyVaultUserObjectId')]"
    },
    "myAppIdentity": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('environmentBasedValues')[parameters('environmentType')].fullDeployedName),'2018-11-01','Full').identity.principalId]"
    },
    "myFullDeployedName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('environmentBasedValues')[parameters('environmentType')].fullDeployedName]"
    },
    "myEnvironmentType": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('environmentType')]"
    },
    "myVnetID": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[concat(resourceId('NetworkRG','Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks','VNETNAME'))]"
    },
    "mySubnetID": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[concat(resourceId('NetworkRG','Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'VNETNAME'), '/subnets/SUBNETNAME')]"
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error message when you deploy this template?

Comment: no errors. The template validates and runs without an error in the AZ CLI window. The app service and keyvault from the template are created as expected. Except the app service doesn't have the VNET/Subnet configured.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the template above does work. I ran it again and check the site and the VNET/Subnet were configured correctly. I don't know if I was looking at a cached version or the wrong instance before but this is ok. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Worked for me as well, thanks for following up and pointing out that the template in your question actually works.