# How to use Existing Vnet and Subnet in ARM Template for Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I want to use Existing Vnet and Subnet for my Logic Apps. Below is the code snippet, I am not sure this is the right way to do it and also I am getting one error as well.

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
  "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
  "name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('logicAppFEname'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "subnetRef": "[resourceId(parameters('vnetRg'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',parameters('vnetName'), parameters('subnetName'))]",
    "isSwift": true
  }
},
```

**Error :**

> Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'my-vnet-01' for type 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config' at line '151' and column '46' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)

ARM Template :

```
  {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "logicAppFEname": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "appInsightName": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "use32BitWorkerProcess": {
        "type": "Bool"
      },
      "location": {
        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Location to deploy resources to."
        }
      },
      "hostingPlanFEName": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "contentStorageAccountName": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "sku": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "skuCode": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "workerSize": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "workerSizeId": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "numberOfWorkers": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "vnetName": {
        "defaultValue": "VirtualNetwork",
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Name of the VNET that the Function App and Storage account will communicate over."
        }
      },
      "subnetName": {
        "type": "String"
      }
    },
    "variables": {
      "privateEndpointFileStorageName": "[concat(parameters('contentStorageAccountName'), '-file-private-endpoint')]",
      "fileShareName": "[concat(toLower(parameters('logicAppFEname')), 'b86e')]"
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
        "name": "[parameters('contentStorageAccountName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
        "sku": {
          "name": "Standard_LRS",
          "tier": "Standard"
        },
        "kind": "StorageV2",
        "properties": {
          "networkAcls": {
            "bypass": "AzureServices",
            "defaultAction": "Deny"
          },
          "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
          "encryption": {
            "services": {
              "file": {
                "keyType": "Account",
                "enabled": true
              },
              "blob": {
                "keyType": "Account",
                "enabled": true
              }
            },
            "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
        "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('contentStorageAccountName'), '/default/', toLower(variables('fileShareName')))]",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[parameters('contentStorageAccountName')]"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
        "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
        "name": "[variables('privateEndpointFileStorageName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares', parameters('contentStorageAccountName'), 'default',toLower(variables('fileShareName')))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "subnet": {
            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnetName'), parameters('subnetName'))]"
          },
          "privateLinkServiceConnections": [
            {
              "name": "MyStorageQueuePrivateLinkConnection",
              "properties": {
                "privateLinkServiceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('contentStorageAccountName'))]",
                "groupIds": [
                  "file"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
        "apiVersion": "2020-02-02",
        "name": "[parameters('logicAppFEname')]",
        "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
        "kind": "web",
        "properties": {
          "Application_Type": "web"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "name": "[parameters('logicAppFEname')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanFEName'))]"
        ],
        "tags": {},
        "kind": "functionapp,workflowapp",
        "identity": {
          "type": "SystemAssigned"
        },
        "properties": {
          "name": "[parameters('logicAppFEname')]",
          "siteConfig": {
            "appSettings": [
              {
                "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                "value": "~3"
              },
              {
                "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                "value": "node"
              },
              {
                "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('appInsightName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
              },
              {
                "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
                "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('appInsightName')), '2015-05-01').ConnectionString]"
              },
              {
                "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('contentStorageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('contentStorageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"
              },
              {
                "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('contentStorageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('contentStorageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"
              },
              {
                "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                "value": "[toLower(variables('fileShareName'))]"
              },
              {
                "name": "APP_KIND",
                "value": "workflowApp"
              },
              {
                "name": "WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL",
                "value": "1"
              },
              {
                "name": "AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensionBundle__id",
                "value": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows",
                "slotSetting": false
              },
              {
                "name": "AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensionBundle__version",
                "value": "[1.*, 2.0.0)",
                "slotSetting": false
              },
              {
                "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET",
                "value": "1",
                "slotSetting": false
              }
            ],
            "use32BitWorkerProcess": "[parameters('use32BitWorkerProcess')]",
            "cors": {
              "allowedOrigins": [
                "https://afd.hosting.portal.azure.net",
                "https://afd.hosting-ms.portal.azure.net",
                "https://hosting.portal.azure.net",
                "https://ms.hosting.portal.azure.net",
                "https://ema-ms.hosting.portal.azure.net",
                "https://ema.hosting.portal.azure.net",
                "https://ema.hosting.portal.azure.net"
              ]
            }
          },
          "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanFEName'))]",
          "clientAffinityEnabled": true
        },
        "resources": [
          {
            "type": "networkconfig",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "name": "virtualNetwork",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
              "[parameters('logicAppFEname')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "subnetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',parameters('vnetName'), parameters('subnetName'))]",
              "swiftSupported": true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanFEName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [],
        "tags": {},
        "sku": {
          "Tier": "[parameters('sku')]",
          "Name": "[parameters('skuCode')]"
        },
        "kind": "",
        "properties": {
          "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanFEName')]",
          "workerSize": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
          "workerSizeId": "[parameters('workerSizeId')]",
          "numberOfWorkers": "[parameters('numberOfWorkers')]",
          "maximumElasticWorkerCount": "20"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Could you please make sure that if your vnet and logic app in the same resource group /locations. For providing vnet names we would you something like `"type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"` and for example please refer this [**SO THREAD**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518717/arm-template-for-appservice-integrating-with-existing-vnet-subnets)

Comment: Yes vnet and logic app is in same resource group and if you want I can paste my template here

Comment: I have shared it. I I figured out how to inject existing vnet but this issue is now that subnet needs to be delegated to serverfarms and due to this I am not able to create private end point and work around on this or this is not allowed